# show div and hide other ones - d3.js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, show-hide, axis-labels

I made a bar chart in d3.js. When I click on one of the ticks, a div appears underneath the bar-graph that is linked to this specific tick. So, there are 24 ticks with 24 matching divs containing information about these ticks.

This works fine, but now I want all others divs to close when I open a new one.

This the code I have so far. I need to press the tick for a second time in order to close it. 
[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A3Cd.png)

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")
     .on("click",clickme)

function clickme(d){
      var info = document.getElementById(""+d+ "");
      if (info.style.display === "none") {
      info.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      info.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This is what my divs look like

```
<div style = "display:none" id="Coal CCS retrofit" class = "hidden"> 1 </div>
<div style = "display:none" id="Coal CCS new built" class = "hidden"> 2 </div>
```

I tried to incorporate this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $answers = $('.hidden');
  $(".member").click(function () {
      var $ans = $(this).next(".hidden").stop(true).slideToggle(100);
      $answers.not($ans).filter('.block').stop(true).slideUp();
  })
});
```

with the following CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

When I use the Jquery, the div pops up, and 'slides up' immediately after this. I think this is because the ticks don't have a class 'member', but I can't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution might be to make your info divs share a common class (e.g. tooltip below), and then hide all of them, before showing the div that was clicked. Sample code:

```
<div id="Coal CCS new built" class = "tooltip"> 1 </div>
<div id="Coal CCS new built" class = "tooltip"> 2 </div>
```

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")
     .on("click",clickme)

function clickme(d){
    // Select element that should be shown
    const element = d3.select("#"+d.id); // Or however you're deriving id

    // Determine whether the element needs to be shown or hidden
    const show = element.style('display') === 'none';

    // Hide any tooltip that may be shown
    d3.selectAll('.tooltip').style('display', 'none');

    // Show element, if appropriate
    if (show) element.style('display', 'block');
}
```